# Regularity assumption in method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am reading Evan's book Partial Differential Equations and I have a question about the method of characterisics for first order PDEs.

Using Evan's notation, one writes $p(s) = \nabla u(x(s))$ and derives an ODE for  $\dfrac{d}{ds} p(s)$. Since $p$ is the gradient of $u$, does this mean that we are assuming that the solution $u$ is in fact $C^2$ smooth, although the PDE itself only needs $C^1$ regularity for $u$?

Comment: Yes. The part where he derives the characteristic ODE is purely formal, so you can just assume $u$ is smooth. Later in the local existence proof, you need $u\in C^2$ for things to work.

Comment: I should say, the existence proof establishes the existence of a $C^2$ solution, so nothing is lost.